# List top 5 processes for a specific user

Tags: grep, sort, ps, top, head

I am trying to get the top five processes of a specific user in a bash:

```
ps -Ao user,uid,comm,pid,pcpu,tty --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6 | grep <username>
```

However, this selects the top 5 processes across the system and then filters out the processes that belong to the specified username. I basically want to flip the logic. Get all processes of a specific user and then filter the top 5.

Comment: So, exchange the `head` and the `grep`?

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pipeline, the `head` command would deliver the first six lines of output from `ps`  to `grep`, no matter what username was mentioned in those lines.  Swapping the `head` and `grep` calls around would mean that the `head` command would only ever see lines from `ps` containing the wanted username. (You also likely want to use `head -n 5`).

Answer (score 0):

ps -u username

It will list user process

You can pipeline output accordingly to get 5 process